# What does it mean: Hope not. She is my sister

Tags: phrase-meaning

This is from a TV show.

Emma and P.J. meets at the park. They each take their baby siblings out in a stroller.

Emma said to P.J.,

I'm really impressed that you take your sister to the park. My brother would never do anything like that.

P.J. replied,

> Hope not. She is my sister.

What does "hope not" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PJ is misunderstanding the ambiguity of "like that", probably on purpose, for comic effect.

"Like that" refers to

> Like PJ taking PJ's sister to the park

So "Like that" means

> My brother taking his sister to the park.

But PJ (pretends) to misunderstand it to mean

> My brother taking PJ's sister to the park.

So she says "I hope not".  She means "I hope your brother isn't taking my sister to the park" because Emma's brother is a stranger to PJ.